# C++ win32 program for creating menu bar(program compiles and runs, window is also displayed but no menu bar appears)

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++, win32gui

I am referring to this tutorial for creating menu bar in window:

http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/menus.html

The program gets successfully compiled and runs. I can see the window but not able to see the menu bar.
What am I missing? I am using Dev-C++ IDE.
My resource.h and programName.rc files are placed in the same folder in which programName.c file is placed.

Please help me.

Comment: Does the program show up using the icon you referenced in the RC file?

Comment: no it does not show the icon also

Comment: Then most certainly the resources had not been linked into the executable.

Comment: How to link resources into executable?

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most certainly the resources are not link into the executable.

You might like to follow the instructions here: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/54934-resource-files-dev-cplusplus.html to added the rc file to the project and though have it linked into the binary resulting form the build process.

Comment: Now I am able to see icon but not the menu bar? what could be wrong?Does it depend on IDE which I am using? can you suggest good IDE for c++ development?

Comment: I am sorry I had IDR_MYMENU in rc file whereas IDR_MENU in source file.Thanks now I can see the menus.Thanks for your help but still can you suggest me good IDEs for C++ development?

Comment: @user1389626: For C++ under windows and optimal integration to **windows** you could use the free VC++ express by microsoft. I only have experience with VC10 and never used any later versions yet. But I assume the main changes refer to win8 integration. Anyhow the free VC10 lacks a resource editor, so if going this direction this link might help: http://www.resedit.net/ As a final note: I never used Dev-C++ so I could not make any assumptions on how it compares to VC++.

Comment: @user1389626: A much more portable approach in terms of platform independence would be the use of Eclipse using the GCC tool chain. Under Linux g++ is native. Under windows you could use the Cygwin environment to have it by hand.